# "Expected expression" in a single liner "else continue"

Tags: python

`Python -V => 3.12.1`

```py
value = "abc" # or could be None in some other cases


def doSomething(v):
   print(f"value is {v}")

for v in range(100):
   doSomething(v) if value else continue
```

[image]

Any ideas how to use a single liner in these kind of situations anyone? TIA

Comment: There is no reason to use a single line here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) that must follow the pattern of

```
or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]
```

You need an expression and the simplest one is `None`. So, you could write it as

```
for v in range(100):
    doSomething(v) if value else None
```

This is slightly more expensive to run and many would not like having a throw-away value like that. A conditional expression resolves to a single value and the intent is to use that value in a larger statement. Here, you are just using the conditional for the side-effect of conditionally calling the function. It's similar to

```
[doSomething(v) for v in range(100) if value]
```

where the list is only created because you wanted to call the function. It's not a bug but may violate some coding standards.

Answer (score 4):

`continue` is a statement; you can't embed a statement in an expression. You need to use an actual `if` statement here, not a conditional expression.

```
for v in range(100):
    if value:
        doSomething(v)
    else:
        continue
```

The `else: continue` is entirely unnecessary, of course;

```
for v in range(1000):
    if value:
        doSomething(v)
```

because the loop will continue any way since nothing follows the `if` statement. (Incidentally, you *could* write `if value: doSomething(v)`, but that style is not recommended.)
If something *did* follow the `if` statement, however, you would typically write

```
for v in range(1000):
    if not value:
        continue
    doSomething(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate one liner solutions for most python problems: List comprehension.
In your case

```
[doSomething(v) for v in range(100) if value]
```